# Distinguish between optional arguments, pathname or file? c language

Tags: c, arguments, filenames, pathname

I am very new with c and less experienced with any other language :/
For an assignment at uni, I am a little stuck on this small part. Essentially I am required to write a 'ls' function that has 4 optional arguments, for example:

```
list [-l] [-f] [pathname] [localfile]
```

Now, the first two are straight forward. To make things more difficult, the 'localfile' doesn't necessarily exist and the 'pathname'(if given) will be located on the server I'm connecting to through a socket (so checking if it is a file is out and checking the pathname is out). I was thinking, check last 4 chars in the string for a '.txt' or something similar. I'm actually completely stumped and will present this problem to my course conveyor tomorrow, if I can't find a solution.

This is a very small part of what I actually have to do but any push in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: You *definitely* want to learn and love and learn to love `getopt`.

Comment: Is  this on  Windows or Linux?

Comment: Linux definitely has it and I don't know any fundamental restriction for windows as well. There is arg_parse function http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Parsing-Program-Arguments.html#Parsing-Program-Arguments

Comment: hmmm I'm liking 'getopt' but it doesn't do too much for my problem :(

Comment: try arg_parse, it has more functionality ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to process argc and argv to get your command line arguments. That is the first thing to work on, getting the arguments - ensuring they are correct, and determining what is being asked for.

```
int main(int argc, char  *argv[])
```

Assuming your are on Linux/Unix, you will need to use the directory functions opendir()/readdir()/closedir() - *dirent.h*.  The **stat()** function will be required to satisfy the -l requirement. **access()** will determine if a file exists and then **stat()** will tell you if the file is a regular file or a directory.

I'd make a struct to hold the four optional arguments and return it from a function called "process_arguments" that takes argc and argv as parameters.

```
struct args {
  bool valid;
  bool l_option;
  bool f_option
  char directory[200]; 
  char filename[200];
}
```

With the requirement for a socket connection you will have to write a "server program" that will be constantly running on the server and a "client program" that it will fork to handle the requests from your local program. Try and locate examples of socket programs.

Another check for whether you have a path string or a filename is to look for the path separator character - '/' if the server is Unix/Linux. This scheme shouldn't have any path separators in filenames, so the presence of one tells you it is a path.

Comment: It's Linux(cygwin) but I do eventually have to make it compatible with windows. But Linux first for now. 
I have already wrote the code to determine the 'command' and have got a *argsList[] of arguments extracted. Just wondering how I should determine if I have a pathname or file. 
I'm will be using stat() for the '-l' argument.

Comment: @RileyVanZeeland Is it allowed to give filename, but not path? If so, I would do the socket stuff and try and CD to that value as if it is a directory and see if that succeeds. Success = directory, failure = file.

Comment: @RileyVanZeeland  You will need a "socket server program" running on your server computer. One of the request that server program (and any clients it forks) will have to handle is "is this a directory" or "CD to this directory" and did that succeed?  So  send the unknown string to the server and have it determine if it is a directory or not.

Comment: Hmm that might be my only option. If there are two arguments (path and file) I'll know what's what and if there is one argument(either path or file), I'll send it anyway and check for directory, if not directory, assume file.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: @RileyVanZeeland You can also check the string for the path separator character. For a remote directory on Unix it would seem they would all have at least one /. And they shouldn't be putting a path in the filename so the filename should not have a /.